# jquery trim last 2 zeros from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array

```
var aa = ["500", "600", "700", "800", "900", "1000", "1100", "1200"]
```

I need to strip last 2 zeros. I have the script like this below but that strips the array values

```
$( '.hasDifficutly span' ).each(function(  ) {
var a = $(this).text();
  var aa = a.split(', ');  

  if (aa.length > 2) {
    aa = [aa.shift(), aa.pop()]
  }  

  $(this).text(aa.slice(0,-2));

});
```

so instead of getting `["500", "1200"]` I get `[]` but I need `["5", "12"]`

Comment: Will they always have two zeroes on the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var aa = ["500", "600", "700", "800", "900", "1000", "1100", "1200", '1'];
var newArray = [];
$.each(aa, function( index, value ) {
    var valPush = parseInt(value)<=99 ? value : value.slice(0,-2);
    newArray.push(valPush);
});
alert(newArray.join(","));
```

here it is, you can use the above code to make it working your way..

working Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d9807kbo/

Answer (score 1):

You can try Array.map() and divise 100:

```
aa.map(function(item){
    return !isNaN(item) && item%100 == 0 ? Math.floor(item/100) : item;
})
```

In your case, modify the code to:

```
$( '.hasDifficutly span' ).each(function(  ) {
    var a = $(this).text();
    var aa = a.split(', ');  
    aa = aa.map(function(item){
         return !isNaN(item) && item%100 == 0 ? Math.floor(item/100) : item;
    });
    $(this).text(aa.join(','));
 });
```

Comment: you would have complete requirement, as this won't work when you don't have zeros at the end. and how if you have value as single digit?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 ok, I just update to check number and single digit :D

Comment: the values will always be the ones in the array. I only worry about 1000 as I don't want it end up 1 instead 10

Comment: @JoshuaNa I'm sure this map() will be ok. 1000/100 = 10, not 1 :D

Comment: Yes, Array.map() is a built-in function, no need jQuery anymore. I love pure js :)